# Can Origen.current_command be nil?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am using the `Origen.current_command` and wonder if it should ever be set to nil?  Is this expected?  BTW, the debug session below is in config/boot.rb.

** EDIT **

Is there any reason why the current_command can't be set earlier in the [Origen commands.rb file](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/commands.rb)?

```
@command = ARGV.shift
@command = ORIGEN_COMMAND_ALIASES[@command] || @command
@global_commands = []

Origen.send :current_command=, @command # line 29
```

thx

```
peologin01:ppekit $ origen p mbist_flow.rb

 8: def ignore_target?
 9:   if Origen.current_command.nil?
10:     binding.pry
11:   elsif Origen.current_command.match(/^t$|^target$|^m$|^mode$/)
12:     true
13:   else
14:     false
15:   end
=> 16: end
[1] pry(main)> ARGV
=> ["mbist_flow.rb"]
[2] pry(main)> Origen.current_command
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason it can't be set earlier if its current location is too late for you.

It probably just evolved in its current location over time and wasn't really intended to be a user facing API until now.